# Writing a Rspec test for an error condition finished with exit

Tags: ruby, rspec, error-handling, exit

I am writing a command line interface to a Ruby gem and I have this method `exit_error`, which acts as an exit error point to all validations performed while processing.

```
def self.exit_error(code,possibilities=[])
  puts @errormsgs[code].colorize(:light_red)
  if not possibilities.empty? then
    puts "It should be:"
    possibilities.each{ |p| puts "  #{p}".colorize(:light_green) }
  end
  exit code
end
```

where `@errormsgs` is a hash whose keys are the error codes and whose values are the corresponding error messages.

This way I may give users customized error messages writing validations like:

```
exit_error(101,@commands) if not valid_command? command
```

where:

```
@errormsgs[101] => "Invalid command." 
@commands = [ :create, :remove, :list ]
```

and the user typing a wrong command would receive an error message like:

```
Invalid command.
It should be:
  create
  remove
  list
```

At the same time, this way I may have bash scripts detecting exactly the error code who caused the exit condition, and this is very important to my gem.

Everything is working fine with this method and this strategy as a whole. But I must confess that I wrote all this without writing tests first. I know, I know... Shame on me!

Now that I am done with the gem, I want to improve my code coverage rate. Everything else was done by the book, writing tests first and code after tests. So, it would be great having tests for these error conditions too.

It happens that I really don't know how to write Rspec tests to this particular situation, when I use `exit` to interrupt processing. Any suggestions?

**Update** => This gem is part of a "programming environment" full of bash scripts. Some of these scripts need to know exactly the error condition which interrupted the execution of a command to act accordingly.

Comment: What is that you want to do with `bash` on this exactly?

Comment: @Inian this gem is part of a "programming environment" which has lots of bash scripts. Some of these scripts need to know the error codes returned by this Ruby command line interface, so they can act accordingly.

Comment: You can get the return code of any command by doing `$?`, you can directly check its value for success/failure check.

Comment: I know that, @Inian. But the program being executed must specify the error code in the `exit` command. If I just raise an error to force interrupting I will just have a non-zero return code indicating the program had an abnormal interruption. I need more than this. I need to specify many different error conditions and have bash dealing with each one in a specific way.

Comment: Your requirements sounds fine, but your inputs are not verifiable, folks here need a minimal verifiable input and expected output to help you with code. So far it is not helping.

Comment: May be a switch case dealing with various exit codes in `bash`?

Comment: Sorry, but... I am having no problems with my inputs and outputs. This is out of the scope of my question. I am only asking **how to write a rspec test to a method ending in a `exit`**. There is nothing wrong with my inputs and outputs. In fact, my gem is working perfectly. I just need to improve my code coverage testing this specific method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example:

```
class MyClass
  def self.exit_error(code,possibilities=[])
    puts @errormsgs[code].colorize(:light_red)
    if not possibilities.empty? then
      puts "It should be:"
      possibilities.each{ |p| puts "  #{p}".colorize(:light_green) }
    end
    exit code
  end
end
```

You could write its rspec to be something like this:

```
describe 'exit_error' do
  let(:errormsgs) { {101: "Invalid command."} }
  let(:commands) { [ :create, :remove, :list ] }
  context 'exit with success'
    before(:each) do
      MyClass.errormsgs = errormsgs # example/assuming that you can @errormsgs of the object/class
      allow(MyClass).to receive(:exit).with(:some_code).and_return(true)
    end

    it 'should print commands of failures'
      expect(MyClass).to receive(:puts).with(errormsgs[101])
      expect(MyClass).to receive(:puts).with("It should be:")
      expect(MyClass).to receive(:puts).with(" create")
      expect(MyClass).to receive(:puts).with(" remove")
      expect(MyClass).to receive(:puts).with(" list")
      MyClass.exit_error(101, commands)
    end
  end

  context 'exit with failure'
    before(:each) do
      MyClass.errormsgs = {} # example/assuming that you can @errormsgs of the object/class
      allow(MyClass).to receive(:exit).with(:some_code).and_return(false)
    end

    # follow the same approach as above for a failure
  end
end
```

Of course this is an initial premise for your specs and might not just work if you copy and paste the code. You will have to do a bit of a reading and refactoring in order to get green signals from rspec.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I know I'll have to adapt, but you put me in the right track. I had no idea about how to start it.